# nested list generator with iterative variable

Tags: python, list, generator, nested-lists

i have a set of variables i want to insert in a nested list

```
im1 = cv2.imread('0_0.jpg') 
im2 = cv2.imread('0_1080.jpg') 
im3 = cv2.imread('960_0.jpg') 
im4 = cv2.imread('960_1080.jpg') 
im5 = cv2.imread('1920_0.jpg') 
im6 = cv2.imread('1920_1080.jpg') 
im7 = cv2.imread('2880_0.jpg') 
im8 = cv2.imread('2880_1080.jpg')
```

i want to create a **custom size nested list** containing **variable with iterative naming**

```
[[im1, im2],[im3, im4], [im5, im6], [im7, im8]]
```

i have already tried creating a simple list generator as below

```
n = 4
m = 2
a = [['im{0}'.format(i)] * m for i in range(n)]
```

but the result still not as i expected, and the variable are in string

```
[['im0', 'im0'], ['im1', 'im1'], ['im2', 'im2'], ['im3', 'im3']]
```

Comment: What do you expect the values to be if not strings?

Comment: Seeing from the names, it seems the OP wants them to be file-paths or something;

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! If you have any new information please update your question with that so that it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I really hope I got this right but I believe you want a list of pairs, and the values should be the class returned from the relevant call for cv2.imread().

**Short answer**

Use eval(), which takes string inputs and convert them to the python value they represent. For example:

```
>>> eval("10+10")
20
```

See a [nice tutorial on eval here](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-eval-built-in-function-601f87db191).

**More details**

Examining your request I see another issue in your code:
You wanted this output:

```
[[im1, im2],[im3, im4], [im5, im6], [im7, im8]]
```

But your loop gave you pairs with the same index not (x, x+1):

```
[['im0', 'im0'], ['im1', 'im1'], ['im2', 'im2'], ['im3', 'im3']]
```

I created an example file that answers the example values you provided, with minimal changes to the code:

```
class Img(object):
    """ I'm an image from imread """

    def __init__(self, var_name):
        self.var_name = var_name

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm of class Img and my var name is {var}".format(var=self.var_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    im1 = Img("im1")
    im2 = Img("im2")
    im3 = Img("im3")
    im4 = Img("im4")
    im5 = Img("im5")
    im6 = Img("im6")
    im7 = Img("im7")
    im8 = Img("im8")

    n = 4
    m = 2
    a = [[eval('im{0}'.format(2*i+1)),eval('im{0}'.format(2*i+2))] for i in range(n)]

    for pair in a:
        print "We are a pair:"
        for obj in pair:
            print obj
```

Since I don't have the images it just demonstrates the pairs are well constructed and are of type Img:

```
$python ./example.py
We are a pair:
I'm of class Img and my var name is im1
I'm of class Img and my var name is im2
We are a pair:
I'm of class Img and my var name is im3
I'm of class Img and my var name is im4
We are a pair:
I'm of class Img and my var name is im5
I'm of class Img and my var name is im6
We are a pair:
I'm of class Img and my var name is im7
I'm of class Img and my var name is im8
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing that Tgilgul's answer is correct, however, I would like to add this solution too, as it seems to me that the underlying questions is not really about the variables.

Also this solution is more dynamic if you were to read in more images from a directory.

```
# List of images
# Can be retrieved by other function
images = ['0_0.jpg','0_1080.jpg','960_0.jpg','960_1080.jpg','1920_0.jpg','1920_1080.jpg','2880_0.jpg','2880_1080.jpg']

# key for each pair
keys = list(set([image.split("_")[0] for image in images]))
```

#### list of pairs

```
pairs = []
for k in keys:
    pair = []
    for image in images:
        if image.split("_")[0] == k:
            # pair.append(image) # the filename
            pair.append(cv2.imread(image)) # the image - not tested

    pairs.append(pair)

print(pairs)
```

filenames out

```
[['960_0.jpg', '960_1080.jpg'], ['1920_0.jpg', '1920_1080.jpg'], ['2880_0.jpg', '2880_1080.jpg'], ['0_0.jpg', '0_1080.jpg']]
```

#### dictionary of pairs

```
pairs = {}
for k in keys:
    pair = []
    for image in images:
        if image.split("_")[0] == k:
            # pair.append(image) # the filename
            pair.append(cv2.imread(image)) # the image - not tested

    pairs[k] = pair

print(pairs)
```

filenames out

```
{
'960': ['960_0.jpg', '960_1080.jpg'], 
'1920': ['1920_0.jpg', '1920_1080.jpg'], 
'2880': ['2880_0.jpg', '2880_1080.jpg'], 
'0': ['0_0.jpg', '0_1080.jpg']
}
```

With both above solutions images could be read where needed in some other function.